# Amcharts Issue Regarding Panel Settings and Ballon

Tags: javascript, amcharts, forex, jstockchart

Need solution for two small questions which i am unable to figure out,

1. I have two charts(multiple panel charts) have only one scroll bar, but my issue is with balloon text, On mouse over on one balloon i need to show two balloon text, is it possible can anyone assist.
2. I have value axis for my charts my problem is regarding sign of the value, if the value is -ve i am getting sign of value, but if the value is +ve i am not getting + sign where as the requirement is such a way that i need to show + sign. I have tried this using panelSettings(prefixOfBig..) but didn't suit my requirement.

Can any one please assist.

Thank you.

Comment: Post some code if you want some help...

Answer (score 0):

1. You could add two graphs with the same data field and then use different balloonText on each of them. Set graph.visibleInLegend = false; to hide the second graph from the legend. Although I imagine one balloon with multiple rows (you can easily do that, as you can have HTML tags in balloonText property) would be a more elegant solution.
2. ValueAxis has labelFunction property. You can use it to format values in any way you want, here is an explanation of how to do it: http://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/replacing-axis-labels-with-arbitrary-text/